# Should we create a "what is meltdown/spectre and will it impact my SQL servers" question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Here is the "canonical" question on the meltdown/spectre vulnerability on InfoSec.SE:

[**Meltdown and Spectre Vulnerabilities**](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/176803/meltdown-and-spectre-vulnerabilities)

Can I/should I create a related question on dba.SE, perhaps something like, "**As a SQL DBA, what do I need to know about the meltdown/spectre vulnerability?**"

Do we even know, yet, how to contextualize this as a DBA?

Is this just yet another OS patch that we simply coordinate with the systems team to apply?

Are there patches available for MS SQL Server (or other products) required to address this vulnerability?

Any way of knowing what the performance impact might be for various kinds of (virtualized or bare-metal) SQL servers?

A couple of blog posts I've found that are starting to discuss this from a SQL server perspective:

- [SQLHA: The No Good, Terrible Processor Flaw and SQL Server Deployments – Nearly Everything You Need To Know](http://sqlha.com/2018/01/04/no-good-terrible-processor-flaw-sql-server-deployments-nearly-everything-need-know/)
- [Thomas LaRock: SQL Server Guidance to Protect Against Meltdown and Spectre Attacks](https://thomaslarock.com/2018/01/sql-server-guidance-protect-meltdown-spectre-attacks/)
- [Brent Ozar: SQL Server Patches for Meltdown and Spectre Attacks](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/01/sql-server-patches-meltdown-spectre-attacks/)

**Edit**: Posted: [As a MS SQL DBA, what do I need to know about the meltdown/spectre vulnerabilities?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194751/as-a-ms-sql-dba-what-do-i-need-to-know-about-the-meltdown-spectre-vulnerability)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This could be a useful Q & A, though a bit broad by our usual standards.

Seems like it might be a good candidate for a Wiki Answer (like [Where to start with Oracle?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/56123)):

> This question's answer is a collaborative effort: if you see something that can be improved, just edit the answer to improve it! *No additional answers can be added here*

So, there would be only one Community Wiki answer that everyone can contribute to, and keep up to date.

I would think one question per product would be best.

Comment: +1 for one per product - I'm going to create a MongoDB one.

Answer (score 6):

## NEVER ASK TO ASK. JUST ASK

If the question is bad, it'll get downvoted or closed *[at worst](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXsQAXx_ao0)*.